# What Visual Cue Is Available To Show Safari 14.1's Tab Bar Is Scrollable?

Tags: safari, tabs

What visual cue is available to show that Safari 14.1's tab bar is scrollable?

I understand that I can scroll it when there are too many tabs to fit.  Other than trying to scroll it and looking to see whether or not it scrolls, how can I *tell* whether it is scrollable?

In some cases, the last visible tab may be partially covered, so that's a tiny cue. In other cases, if the windows size is "just wrong", all visible tabs are fully rendered.

Is there a cue I'm missing? Is there a cue I can enable? Is there an extension that would provide a cue?

Comment: You mean other than they're squished up at one end & you can't read them all? e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyovD.png

Comment: Wow. That's subtle.  Check out the two tabs with star icons on the right.  https://imgur.com/a/mEXNpBC. The difference between star #1 and star #2 must be the "squished up" Tetsujin references.  Looks like that's the visual cue.  If you'll post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah, I don't use pinned min-tabs with icons… can't tell them apart, so mine is a lot less subtle a cue than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments…

They do scrunch up at one end - though it's not exactly the clearest visual cue as everything is in shades of mid-grey

[image]

Extract of OP's use-case with mini-icons - probably makes it even harder to see…

[image]